# Can I apply for tourist visa for US 6 months before I travel?

Tags: usa

I am Cambodian and living in Australia with bridging visa and I am planning to travel to USA for couple week in July 2018 to join our friends' wedding. So my question is how far could I apply for the visa before I travel date? like can I apply 6 months before I travel? and I had read some posts here mentioned that the validity of the visa is 6 months And I had read on the US visa website stated that the application might take 30 days or up to 60days in case for further processing. Thanks and really appreciate with all the answers.

Comment: You can apply for a Visa 6 months ahead so while in the interview session,You can then inform the consular your desired duration of stay if given the Visa.

Comment: B visa visitors are typically admitted for six months, but the visas are normally valid for a longer period that can be up to ten years.  The period of validity depends on your nationality.